# Xen Cloud Platform

Tags: xen, xenserver

Has anyone tried this one in a production environment yet?

As far as I can tell its basically Citrix' solution rewrapped as open source. But does it as of today provide the exact same features as XenServer 5.5?

Especially I wonder about HA features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is eucalyptus bundled with the latest ubuntu (9.10) which is essentially an open source version of the amazon cloud platform.

I'm not sure if this is suitable for yourself, but it might be worth considering.

However, myself I use Xen on CentOS 5 in production without any real problems.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon, Rackspace, Eucalyptus, etc. use Xen.  Xen is NOT XenServer wrapped as open source.  Xen is the base package that is then repackaged by Citrix, Oracle, Sun, Virtual Iron (RIP) and others and sold as commercial virtualization.  Xen is not in any way "stripped down", it is actually more full featured as it gets the features first before the commercial variants get them downstream.

Citrix does "own" the Xen project but it is fully OSS and XenServer from Citrix is a derivative of it.

HA is a cloud doesn't necessarily mean anything, though, as the cloud itself is HA and the Xen image can migrate between underlying nodes.  So you think about clouds differently than normal virtualization since with normal, in house virtualization, you put together several virt head ends into an HA cluster and that... for all purposes, is an in house cloud.

We run Xen via CentOS (not ON CentOS) here as well.  It's awesome.

Comment: Good input but how about my question? IN regards to XenServer 5.5 vs XCP 0.1? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using XCP on production environment. Currently using XCP 1.0 in 6 physical servers with around 20 vms running at the time, everything connected with a NetApp storage with 3TB usable, NIC bonding in some cases, automated backups and things...

Everything working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

XCP 1.1 - the latest version is based on Xen 3.4.x - quite stable - Linux 2.6.18

If you want the bleeding edge try XenServer 6.0 from Citrix - based on Xen 4.1 - Linux 2.6.32

I have been using both in our labs - 4P and 2P servers, NFS storage - 150+ VMs .....almost no major issues

oh, BTW XCP - is almost fully featured as Citrix XenServer....